# iOS, Substituting outlet constraint for programmatic one: IBNSLayoutConstraint issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, xib

I am going through Big Nerd Ranch, the very end of 20th chapter, iOS textbook, and they are trying to substitute two constraints on `width` and `height` of an `imageView` called `thumbnailView` for one programmatic constraint and `height` constraint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.thumbnailView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.thumbnailView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                multiplier:1
                                  constant:0];
[self.thumbnailView addConstraint:constraint];
```

So, they delete one constraint property: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewWidthConstraint` (in the class, not in the `.xib)` leaving `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewHeightConstraint` behind. In the respective `.xib` they check `Remove at build time` for the `width` of `thumbnailView` constraint and the program starts crashing (it was working perfectly before with two constraints' outlets) with the following error (in Xcode 7):

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named IBNSLayoutConstraint'`

If I uncheck `remove at build time` it crashes with the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<BNRItemCell 0x7ba87800> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageViewWidthConstraint.'`

The `width` and `height` constraints outlets are used in the class to adjust to user's font size changes.

Would be great if anyone could please explain why the program starts crashing and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted the outlet from your code, but you didn't disconnect it in your storyboard (or xib).

Control-click your view controller in the document outline to see the stale connection:

[image: broken connection]

That teeny tiny itty bitty little yellow triangle tells you that Xcode is smart enough to know that there's no outlet named `imageViewWidthConstraint`, but too stupid to give a warning on the storyboard scene or even a warning during compilation.

Click the ✖︎ on the connection to disconnect it.

Incidentally, you can create that aspect-ratio constraint directly in the storyboard or xib now, but I'm guessing you couldn't back when that book was written.